# Missing .DS_Store file (Macbook Pro 2016 running Monterey)

Tags: finder, time-machine, folders, desktop, monterey

I had entered Time Machine just to check when my earliest backup had taken place (did not restore anything). When I came out of Time Machine, I found all my desktop files completely rearranged, which is a major hassle for me.

Upon pressing `shift+command+.` I found that this might be because no `.DS_Store` file exists on my desktop. Is this the real issue? I know that `.DS_Store` files need to store things like folder positions/icons, but then if such a file was missing, wouldn't I have found my desktop folder rearranged every time I booted?

What is the solution to this issue, can I manually create a `.DS_Store` file which my Mac can then fill in with the requisite folder info?

Comment: `shift+command+.` shows "hidden" files, but .DS_Store does not count as a hidden file for Finder - it just seems not to exist. To see .DS_Store you need to use `ls -la` in Terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working backwards in your questions:

You should not attempt to create a `.DS_Store` file. macOS will create one when needed to hold (as you know) metadata about the folder. Attempts to create and/or modify `.DS_Store` either don't work (a good outcome) or cause no end of issues.

Regarding your *apparent* lack of `.DS_Store`:

- Monterey's Finder does not show `.DS_Store` even when you enable showing hidden files. This is a change from previous versions. I suggest this is a good thing as the unwary user will not tamper with what can't be seen!
- Nevertheless, the `.DS_Store` does exist and can be shown in the Terminal app, using the command `ls -la`.

So the apparent lack of `.DS_Store` is not the cause of your problem.

Exactly what happened when you entered and the exited Time Machine, I can't help you with.

Personally, I find the weird Time Machine interface unresponsive and unreliable - much worse than in previous macOS. I prefer to use Finder looking directly at the Time Machine backup volume and its snapshots.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for the late response, had come down with covid unfortunately. The same thing happened again recently though – turns out entering time machine and exiting it completely rearranges my Desktop. I suspect it leads to a deletion of .DS_Store, but haven't been able to find any resources on this, oh well!